# Why pandas .last('1W') don't show last 7 days?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to extract a max value from a Pandas Dataframe with a daytime as index, I'm using .last('1W').
My data goes from the first day of month (2020-09-01 00:00:00). It seems to work properly until I reach today (monday 07/09/2020). At first I supposed that .last() takes the last days of week from starting value (sunday I guess) instead of the last 7 days (as I assumed) but, what confuses me is that if I extend the hours, the resulting dataframe shifts the first sample too...

I'm try to simulate this with:

```
import pandas as pd

i = pd.date_range('2020-09-01', periods=24*6+5, freq='1H')
values = range(0, 24*6+5 )
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': values}, index=i)
print(df)
print(df.last('1W'))
```

With output:

```
                       A
2020-09-01 00:00:00    0
2020-09-01 01:00:00    1
2020-09-01 02:00:00    2
2020-09-01 03:00:00    3
2020-09-01 04:00:00    4
...                  ...
2020-09-07 00:00:00  144
2020-09-07 01:00:00  145
2020-09-07 02:00:00  146
2020-09-07 03:00:00  147
2020-09-07 04:00:00  148

[149 rows x 1 columns]
                       A
2020-09-06 05:00:00  125
2020-09-06 06:00:00  126
2020-09-06 07:00:00  127
2020-09-06 08:00:00  128
2020-09-06 09:00:00  129
2020-09-06 10:00:00  130
2020-09-06 11:00:00  131
2020-09-06 12:00:00  132
2020-09-06 13:00:00  133
2020-09-06 14:00:00  134
2020-09-06 15:00:00  135
2020-09-06 16:00:00  136
2020-09-06 17:00:00  137
2020-09-06 18:00:00  138
2020-09-06 19:00:00  139
2020-09-06 20:00:00  140
2020-09-06 21:00:00  141
2020-09-06 22:00:00  142
2020-09-06 23:00:00  143
2020-09-07 00:00:00  144
2020-09-07 01:00:00  145
2020-09-07 02:00:00  146
2020-09-07 03:00:00  147
2020-09-07 04:00:00  148

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The first value in df is 0 at 2020-09-01 00:00:00

But,

When I try to apply last('1W'), the selection goes from 2020-09-06 05:00:00, to the last value, instead of the last 7 days... as I assumed, nor from 2020-09-06 00:00:00 if the operator works from sunday to sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an offset of 7 days, why not use the `Day` offset, rather than the `Week`?

`"1W"` offset isn't the same as `"7D"` because `"1W"` starting on a Monday in a two-week dataset where the last row is Tuesday will have only 2 days. `"2W"` will include previous week (Monday-Sunday) + (Monday-Tuesday).

You can see the effects of changing the start day of the week by calling the offset class directly, like so:

```
week_offset = pd.tseries.offsets.Week(n=1, weekday=0) # week starting Monday
day_offset = pd.tseries.offsets.Day(n=7) # or simply "7D"

df.last(day_offset)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go this way. What I don't understand yet is the hours shifting on the beginning of the extracted df. It's not supposed to start at 00:00:00?